# How to check text in editText and switch between activity accordingly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have written a simple code to check username and password entered by user and to act accordingly.
However when I run it I am getting error asking to FORCE QUIT
Please find the code:
Plz help

```
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextUsername);
      EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
      String CheckUsername = username.getText().toString();
      String CheckPassword = password.getText().toString();

      TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewErrorMsg);
      if(CheckUsername=="")
        status.setText("please enter username");
      if(CheckPassword=="")
        status.setText("please enter password");
      if(CheckUsername=="xyz" && CheckPassword == "abcd") {
        i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } else {
        i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AppLockActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Please add the crash Log. So far the part of the Code you show here seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE CheckUsername.equals("") and CheckUsername.equals("abcd") equals compares value of 2 objects where as = compares whether they are same object.